# CakePHP model fails to grab table association

Tags: php, cakephp, model, associations

I'm working with CakePHP to develop a web application that has a few tables and some relationships between them. In this instance I have a series of meetings which reference a calendar year, a department and the relevant school however the model fails to grab the associated table information when data is returned from the controller to the view.

There is already existing `$belongsTo` relationships between staff and the department and school they belong to and I also managed to grab the associated meeting when the calendar array is returned on the calendar index but ideally I want to be able to list all the meetings with the names of calendars, departments and schools rather than the id field stored in the meetings table.

Here are my tables:

```
dbo.meetings
    id (int) *primary key*
    calendar_id (int)
    department_id (int)
    school_id (int)
    created (datetime2(7))
    modified (datetime2(7))

dbo.calendar
    id (int) *primary key*
    name (nvarchar(50))
    startdate (datetime2(7))
    enddate (datetime2(7))
    created (datetime2(7))
    modified (datetime2(7))

dbo.schools
    id (int) *primary key*
    name (nvarchar(255))
    (other fields)

dbo.departments
    id (int) *primary key*
    name (nvarchar(255))
    (other fields)
```

Here is the controller for Meetings:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController','Controller');

class MeetingsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Form');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->set('meetings', $this->Meeting->find('all'));
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the model for Meeting:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel','Model');

class Meeting extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $recursive = -1;

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Calendar' => array(
            'className' => 'Calendar',
            'foreignKey' => 'calendar_id'
        ),
        'School' => array(
            'className' => 'School',
            'foreignKey' => 'school_id'
        ),
        'Department' => array(
            'className' => 'Department',
            'foreignKey' => 'department_id'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Currently the `index.ctp` file in `/View/Meetings` just contains `<?php echo var_dump($meetings); ?>` which is printing out the array until I can get the association working and then I will restyle it as required.

Here is what the array looks like atm:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Meeting"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"] => string(1) "1"
      ["calendar_id"] => string(1) "1"
      ["department_id"] => string(2) "33"
      ["school_id"] => string(1) "1"
      ["created"] => NULL
      ["modified"] => NULL
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason it just won't fetch the calendar, department and school details that it should and I want it to. Can anyone help?

**Edit: Model for School**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel','Model');

class School extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => 'A school name is required.'
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Your associations look wrong. Could you confirm what the models for the `calendar`, `schools` and `departments` tables are called?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Calendar, Schools and Departments respectively

Comment: Is there a reason why you are ignoring Cake's naming conventions? It will only make your life harder!

Comment: @drmonkeyninja, I assume you are referring to the use of plural and non-plural naming? If so, I struggled to come up with the plural for calendar as calendars didn't sound right.

Comment: Model names are singular. You can test Cake's inflector using http://inflector.cakephp.org/.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja, I'll bare that in mind for the future but that doesn't explain why it works fine for the staff relationships with departments and schools but doesn't like the meetings relationships with schools, calendars and departments.

Comment: Could you update your question with the Schools model as I suspect you've set it up wrong.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I have added the School model code into the original post and have renamed it now to remove the plural so it's just 'School' and have updated all the other references as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are enabling the [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) for your model's using `public $actsAs = ['Containable'];`:-

```
App::uses('AppModel','Model');

class Meeting extends AppModel {
    public $recursive = -1;
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Calendar',
        'School',
        'Department'
    );
}
```

To apply Containable to all models set it in AppModel so that each model inherits the behaviour. Also, as long as you stick to CakePHP naming conventions you don't need to specify the `className` and `foreignKey` of your associations.

Now `$this->Meeting->find('all')` in your `MeetingsController` should return all the associated data along with the meeting. If you only want it to return some of the associated data you can pass the `contain` option to the `find`. For example:-

```
$this->Meeting->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'contain' => array(
            'School',
            'Department'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: It complains about an unexpected '[' on line 6 which is the line `public $actsAs = ['Containable'];`

Comment: @Daniel, sorry. You're obviously using an old version of PHP that doesn't recognise the `[]` array shorthand. Just replace the square brackets with `array()`. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4 we've been able to replace `array()` with `[]`. Seeing as support for 5.4 ended two days ago you should really be working with PHP 5.5 as a minimum, although I appreciate that isn't always possible.

Comment: Oops! I think the server I am hosted with is a couple of sub-versions out of date. This is the array that the index.ctp returns: `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Meeting"]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["calendar_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["department_id"]=> string(2) "33" ["school_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["created"]=> NULL ["modified"]=> NULL } } }`

Comment: @Daniel have you tried explicitly listing the models to be returned using the `contain` option like in the final snippet of code above?